# Decimal Representation of Real Numbers

Tags: analysis

Find integers x,y such that the repeating decimal 0.712341234.... = x/y.

I would actually do this problem if the 7 was not there. If the 7 was not there, my proof would be as follows.

proof:

Let z = 0.12341234...

Then 10^4z = 1234.1234

10^4z - z = 1234

z = 1234/(10^4 - 1)

x = 1234, y = 10^4-1

So my question is, how would this change when there is a random number thrown in there that is not part of the repeating decimal?

Edit: Proof after hints given

Let Let z = 0.712341234...

Then 10z = 7.1234...

10z - 7 = 0.1234...

10^4*(10z - 7) = 1234.1234...

10^4*(10z-7) - (10z-7) = 1234

(10z-7) * 10^4 - 1 = 1234

(10z-7) = 1234/(10^4 - 1)

10z = 1234/(10^4-1) + 7

z = (1234/(10^4-1) + 7)/10

x = 1234/(10^4-1) + 7, y = 10

I mean this does give me the correct answer, but x isn't exactly an integer.

Comment: Multiply by $10$, subtract $7$.  Later, add $7$, divide by $10$.

Comment: It wouldn't change anything at all.

Comment: z = (1234/(10^4-1) + 7)/10, now simplify the right hand side until you have a fraction, the numerator is x, the denominator is y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=.712341234.... $

$10000x=7123.41234..... $

$9999x =7122.7$

$x =\frac {71227}{99990} $

May be able to reduce. Or maybe not.

The irregular 7 doesn't change anything seriously.

$1/n $ will reduce to a purely repeating pattern but most $m/n $ will not.

...or if you prefer (it's the same thing really)

Let $10x =7.12341234....$

Let $y=.12341234$

$y=\frac {1234}{9999} $

$10x =7+ \frac {1234}{9999} $

$x=\frac 7 {10}+ \frac {1234}{99990} $

$x=\frac {7*9999+1234}{99990}$

$x=\frac {69993+1234}{99990} $

$x=\frac {71227}{99990} $

Comment: I myself prefer the classic

\begin{align}10x&=7.\overline{1234}\\
100000x&=71234.\overline{1234}\\
99990x&=71234-7=71227\\
\implies x&=\frac{71227}{99990}\end{align}

Comment: The OP already assignes a special meaning to the variables x an y in his question. I think it is not a good idea to use  it with a different meaning in your answer,

Comment: Meh... he asked how to do it. From start.  Variables aren't set in stone.  (By definition).

Comment: Fimpellizieri, I'm not sure I see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

$$0.7\overline{1234} = 0.7 + 0.0\overline{1234}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
0.7\overline{1234}
&= \frac{7.\overline{1234}}{10}\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\left(7+0.\overline{1234}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\left(7+\frac{1234}{9999}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{7\cdot 9999}{9999} + \frac{1234}{9999}\right)\\
&= \frac{7\cdot 9999 + 1234}{10\cdot 9999}\\
&= \frac{71227}{99990}
\end{align}
Therefore $x=71227$ and $y=99990$.